# No KeyDown event on my VB.NET Webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm new to VB.NET webform development, but an old VB/Access developer.
I've used Keydown, Keypress events before in my normal development but cannot find this event with this new web development project I'm starting.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the fact it's a web-form.  However when I search I can't find others with this issue so thought I'd ask it here.  Below is a screen-shot of the events I have on the text control on the web-form where I'm trying to put the keypress event.

(I wanted to attach my picture showing you the events in the list but I don't have 10 reputation points so won't let me include it).

Is this event not available for web-form development?  Essentially what I want to do is have the page check that there is text is both the txtUsername and txtPassword controls before enabling the "Log In" command button.

All I have in the drop-down list for the control is:
(Declarations)
DataBinding
Disposed
Init
Load
PreRender
TextChanged
Unload

Comment: Please go learn a little about the Web before you try to translate your desktop skills to the web. If you want to do something on every keypress, then you want to do it on the client side, in JavaScript. You really don't want to do a request to the server for every key that is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<asp:TextBox id="Foo" runat="server"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="Bar"
                ControlToValidate="Foo"
                Display="Static"
                ErrorMessage="*"
                runat="server"/>
```

And in your submit button's click handler:

```
If Page.IsValid Then 
    ...
Else
    ...
End If
```

You will probably also want to use the HTML5 [`required`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#required) attribute:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Foo" runat="server" required="required" />
```

You might also consider using [`aria-required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-required_attribute):

```
<asp:TextBox id="Foo" runat="server" required="required" aria-required="true" />
```